# Get URL location pathname

Tags: url, location, switch-statement, pathname

Let's say I have a dummy website URL: http://company.com/something.

I need to grab the path: /something and use a switch case to redirect to a new URL using javascript.

Can someone please guide me?

```
var URL;
var url_param = location.pathname;

switch(url_param) {
     case "/how-to-do-this":
          URL = '/your-new-destination/';

     default:
          URL: '/thankyou/';

console.log("your new URL is: " + URL);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of your earlier question [switch case url javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968307/switch-case-url-javascript)

Comment: You really should include a tag to indicate the language in your question.

Comment: I apologize, it's javascript

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Javascript

```
var URL;

switch(window.location.pathname) {
     case "/how-to-do-this":
          URL = '/your-new-destination/';

     default:
          URL= '/thankyou/';
}
console.log("your new URL is: " + URL);
```